# What is wrong about the way I am using watch()?

Tags: javascript, yui

```
makeRow : function() {
            this.rowDiv = Y.Node.create("<div/>").addClass('rowDiv'),//.set('id', i),
            this.rowUL = Y.Node.create("<ul/>").addClass('rowUL'),
            this.handle = Y.Node.create("<li/>").addClass('handle'),
            this.plusImg = Y.Node.create("<img/>").set('src', 'images/plus.png').addClass('plus'),
            this.between = Y.Node.create("<div/>").addClass('between'),
            this.rowDel = Y.Node.create("<img/>").addClass('rowDel').set('src', 'images/redx.png'),
            this.rowDelLI = Y.Node.create("<li/>").addClass('delLI'),
            this.expand = Y.Node.create("<li/>").addClass('expand').set('innerHTML', 'expand?');


        this.rowUL.append(this.handle);
        this.rowUL.append(this.expand);
        this.rowDelLI.append(this.rowDel);
        this.rowDiv.append(this.rowDel);
        this.between.append(this.plusImg);
        this.rowDiv.append(this.rowUL);
        this.rowDiv.append(this.between);

        this.expanded = false;
        this.phrases = [];
        this.hiddenPhrases = [];

        //When I print this.rowDiv it returns the id, so hopefully I can treat this as a string of the id
        this.rowDiv.parentMakeRow = this;
        this.id = "<Object makeRow: id=" + id++ +">";

        this.watch("rowUL", function(id, oldval, newval){
            console.log('changed');
        });

        this.toString = function() {
            return this.id;
        }
```

Is it because I am using literal notation?  Is it because this is in an enclosure?

I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'watch'

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: *"Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're intended primarily for debugging use.  In addition, using watchpoints has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true when used on global objects, such as window. You can usually use setters and getters or proxies instead. See Browser compatibility for details."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: Looks like you are not using Firefox.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was only in FireFox